# foreach loop only show one item if items are same

Tags: c#, foreach

Well let's say i have a foreach loop which look likes below

```
items = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'red', 'yellow']
foreach var item in items:
    print(item)
```

is there any way to show repeated items once?

Comment: I don't think that this is C#

Comment: I don't think that this is Python :)

Comment: @minitech - It looks closer to Python than C# to me - if the second line were 'for item in items:` then it would be valid Python.

Comment: for python: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502263/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use LINQ's [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) extension:

```
foreach(var item in items.Distinct()) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

And just in case you actually mean Python:

```
distinct = list(set(items))
distinct.sort(lambda a, b: items.index(a) - items.index(b))

for item in distinct:
    print(item)
```